# Why the plus operator not working in regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to JavaScript, and I made regex to validate decimal values for eg. `(10.12, 100.22, 5.5 etc)`. It accepts 3 digits and 2 decimals. I tested this regex on https://regex101.com/ and it works fine.

```
/^[0-9]{1,3}+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

But the problem comes when I use this regex in Vue, the plus (`+`) operator which is used in regex giving an error:

```
Invalid regular expression: /^[0-9]{1,3}+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/: Nothing to repeat
```

Comment: Switch in regex101.com from php to javascript - it complains about syntax too

Comment: What is the point of having "1 to 3 numbers, at least once"? That's the same as "1 or more numbers"!

Comment: *I tested this regex on https://regex101.com/ and it works fine.* - No, [it does not](https://regex101.com/r/C1JLVE/1) if you test *properly*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` thats mean "one or more" is not required in this case as you need to match exactly one.

Add round brackets around the first part for matching both integer and decimal part.

```js
var n = '120.50';
var m1 = n.match(/^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/);
var m2 = n.match(/(^[0-9]{1,3})(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/);
console.log(m1, m2);
```

Comment: The correct answer is *remove `+`*. Quantifying `(^[0-9]{1,3})`  does not make sense (although yields the correct result) since there can't be more than 1 *start of string* positions.

Comment: That's true. Brackets are needed if you wanna match both integer and decimal part of the number